# How to print image with text from android phone to Bluetooth printer.?

Tags: android, bluetooth, printers

I want to print some text with image which is reside on my android phone to Bluetooth printer but text is successfully printed and image is not printed on paper.

I using following code:

```
public class SendingdataActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
static final UUID MY_UUID =
UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
static String address = "50:C3:00:00:00:00";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
Toast.makeText(this,
"Bluetooth is not available.",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
return;
}


if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
Toast.makeText(this,
"Please enable your BT and re-run this program.",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
finish();
return;
}
final SendData sendData = new SendData();
Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View view) {
sendData.sendMessage();
}
});
}
class SendData extends Thread {
private BluetoothDevice device = null;
private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
private OutputStream outStream = null;

public SendData(){
device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
try
{
 btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
}
catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
try {
btSocket.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
try {
btSocket.close();
} catch (IOException e2) {
}
}
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connected to " + device.getName(),    
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
try {
outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}

public void sendMessage()
{
try {
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.white);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,baos); //bm is the bitmap object
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(b.length), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
outStream.write(b);
outStream.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
}
}
}
}
```

This code works and print only text on paper.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long time I am created an app to print image on bluetooth printer by using following steps:
1. Connect your Bluetooth device with Android phone
2. Call senddatatodevice() method when you want to send data on printer
3. code executed within senddatatodevice() is like bellow.

```
    private static void senddatatodevice() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        //base64 image string
    String  sig="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";
  byte[] imageAsBytes = android.util.Base64
                .decode(sig, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

        btMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0,
                imageAsBytes.length);


        Bitmap bitmapOrg = resizeImage(btMap, 384,
                150);// Bit
        byte[] sendbuf = StartBmpToPrintCode(bitmapOrg, 0);
       /*byte[] a=t2.getBytes();


       byte[] combined = new byte[a.length + sendbuf.length];

       System.arraycopy(a,0,combined,0         ,a.length);
       System.arraycopy(sendbuf,0,combined,a.length,sendbuf.length);*/
    mbtOutputStream = mbtSocket.getOutputStream();
    mbtOutputStream.write(sendbuf);
    mbtOutputStream.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public static Bitmap resizeImage(Bitmap bitmap, int w, int h) {
    Bitmap BitmapOrg = bitmap;
    int width = BitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = BitmapOrg.getHeight();
    int newWidth = w;
    int newHeight = h;

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleWidth);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapOrg, 10,10, width,
            height, matrix, true);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
private static byte[] StartBmpToPrintCode(Bitmap bitmap, int t) {
    byte temp = 0;
    int j = 7;
    int start = 0;
    if (bitmap != null) {
        int mWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
        int mHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] mIntArray = new int[mWidth * mHeight];
        byte[] data = new byte[mWidth * mHeight];
        bitmap.getPixels(mIntArray, 0, mWidth, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
        encodeYUV420SP(data, mIntArray, mWidth, mHeight, t);
        byte[] result = new byte[mWidth * mHeight / 8];
        for (int i = 0; i < mWidth * mHeight; i++) {
            temp = (byte) ((byte) (data[i] << j) + temp);
            j--;
            if (j < 0) {
                j = 7;
            }
            if (i % 8 == 7) {
                result[start++] = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }
        if (j != 7) {
            result[start++] = temp;
        }

        int aHeight = 24 - mHeight % 24;
        byte[] add = new byte[aHeight * 48];
        byte[] nresult = new byte[mWidth * mHeight / 8 + aHeight * 48];
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, nresult, 0, result.length);
        System.arraycopy(add, 0, nresult, result.length, add.length);

        byte[] byteContent = new byte[(mWidth / 8 + 4)
                * (mHeight + aHeight)];// ´òÓ¡Êý×é
        byte[] bytehead = new byte[4];// Ã¿ÐÐ´òÓ¡Í·
        bytehead[0] = (byte) 0x1f;
        bytehead[1] = (byte) 0x10;
        bytehead[2] = (byte) (mWidth / 8);
        bytehead[3] = (byte) 0x00;
        for (int index = 0; index < mHeight + aHeight; index++) {
            System.arraycopy(bytehead, 0, byteContent, index * 52, 4);
            System.arraycopy(nresult, index * 48, byteContent,
                    index * 52 + 4, 48);

        }
        return byteContent;
    }
    return null;

}

public static void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] rgba, int width,
        int height, int t) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    int[] U, V;
    U = new int[frameSize];
    V = new int[frameSize];
    final int uvwidth = width / 2;
    int r, g, b, y, u, v;
    int bits = 8;
    int index = 0;
    int f = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            r = (rgba[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            g = (rgba[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
            b = (rgba[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
            // rgb to yuv
            y = ((66 * r + 129 * g + 25 * b + 128) >> 8) + 16;
            u = ((-38 * r - 74 * g + 112 * b + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            v = ((112 * r - 94 * g - 18 * b + 128) >> 8) + 128;
            // clip y
            // yuv420sp[index++] = (byte) ((y < 0) ? 0 : ((y > 255) ? 255 :
            // y));
            byte temp = (byte) ((y < 0) ? 0 : ((y > 255) ? 255 : y));
            if (t == 0) {
                yuv420sp[index++] = temp > 0 ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0;
            } else {
                yuv420sp[index++] = temp > 0 ? (byte) 0 : (byte) 1;
            }

            // {
            // if (f == 0) {
            // yuv420sp[index++] = 0;
            // f = 1;
            // } else {
            // yuv420sp[index++] = 1;
            // f = 0;
            // }

            // }

        }

    }
    f = 0;
}
```

Comment: Simply call senddatatodevice() from your device when bluetooth is connecetd.

Comment: i try this but app is crashed. my mail id:  inam174@gmail.com please show the code

Comment: What is `mbtSocket` here? is it  object of process?

Comment: mbtSocket is object of BluetoothSocket.

Comment: Hello @RaviShankerYadav i want to print a image and I implement your soulution but not work for me. I attach image link of my printing receipt [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ys400EGSOOtiFdXsw0XUl37Mm0ulg9JP/view?usp=sharing) please check this