# How to print in Android without API19 and without CloudPrint

Tags: android, printing

I am trying to print a simple A4 Page from my app, however, not sure how to approach this. I am using Jellybean (4.1.2) and API 17.

I read up on the [PrintManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintManager.html) and [PrintDocumentAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/print/PrintDocumentAdapter.html) classes, which looks like a good class to use, however I am not going to use kitkat, so I need a solution that works in previous APIs and offline aka not CloudPrint. I know for a fact this should be possible because I have used other applications like S-Memo to print documents and notes to a wireless printer and my tablet has Jellybean (4.1.2) installed. I just want to print to a printer using wifi direct. Any Ideas ?

T.I.A

Comment: May this link gives you some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21854362/how-to-print-image-with-text-from-android-phone-to-bluetooth-printer

Comment: @RaviDev, thx for the link, however, the method described in that thread explains how to send data (bytes) to a Bluetooth printer. In my case, my printer does not have bluetooth, however it does have Wifi.

Comment: Guys, I might have found a solution. As I have a samsung printer, I can make use of the samsung mobile print API described in this thread:http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=GeneralB&messageId=229745